# UITextView invalid glyph index

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have a `UITextView`, created in a storyboard.  I create a series of `NSAttributedString`s from some html.  The html is well formed, but some of it contains a table tag.  The first use of the UITextView does not generate any errors.  If I update the UITextView with "simple html", it seems to work fine.  If I then update with a string generated from html with a table, then I get:

> _NSLayoutTreeSetOutsideDrawsUponLineFragmentAtGlyphIndex invalid glyph index 0

The glyph index varies and if the text is long, I may get a number of these.

This is a sample string (contains some Unicode Tibetan):

```
static let record2 = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">" +
"<html>" +
"<head>" +
"<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">" +
"<title></title>" +
"</head>" +
"<body>" +
"" +
"<h1>This is a partial list </h1><br /><table><tr><td>888</td><td>8888 88</td><td>9999</td></tr></table><br />77777 ཞུ་དག་པ་<br /></body></html>"
```

I create the NSAttributedString thus:

```
func displayRecord() -> () {
    do {
       let attrString = try NSAttributedString(data: TestData.records[cnt].data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
       self.textView.attributedText = attrString
       } catch {
         print(error)
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to debug this.  Furthermore, when I print a String.description it looks like the NSAttributedString contains references to an NSTableView, which is an OS X only library.

Comment: It looks like an iOS SDK issue, please fill Apple radar at bugreport.apple.com. To solve your problem, you can use `DTFoundation` + `DTCoreText` libraries (over cocoapods, for example), there support of attributed text from HTML is implemented on their own, so maybe it will work for you, with `DTAttributedTextView`.

Comment: @DisableR The DTAttributedTextView, DTCoreText libraries looked really useful and in some ways better than what Apple currently supports in NSAttributedString.  However, I don't think they have any support for the HTML table tag.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, the developer of the library is looking for sponsors to make that feature, https://github.com/cocoanetics/dtcoretext/issues/144. He wrote that you can hire him to do that :D